# Отменить несколько add-ов в git

Tags: git

Здравствуйте.

```
git init
echo first > file
git add file
echo second > file
git add file
echo third > file
git add file
```

Как после выполнения этих команд достать первую или вторую версию файла добавленную в индекс?

Comment: Первые две версии файла внутри Гита пока хранится, но они потеряли привязку к имени. Их можно найти, но в большом репозитории это может быть не тривиально. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что есть магическая команда для этого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала делаете:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

Затем смотрите в `.git/lost-found/` и подкаталогах вроде `.git/lost-found/other/` не появилось ли там чего-нибудь из того, что вы потеряли.

Чтобы не заниматься все этим лучше делать коммиты чаще. Их всегда можно склеить в один коммит вызовом `git rebase -i origin` и так далее.

Comment: тоже так делаю =) только вот в большой куче без частых коммитов тяжело было найти нужное, но со временем стал коммитить чаще и все упростилось =)